# Push column to the top on mobile view using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have four columns using the Bootstrap column classes

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @include('schedulizer.classes-panel')
    @include('schedulizer.time-span-options-panel')
    @include('schedulizer.other-options-panel')
</div>

<div class="col-md-9 col-centered">
    @include('schedulizer.schedule-panel')
</div>
```

They look like this:

[image]

In mobile view, the schedule, the main element, is pushed all the way to the bottom like this:

[image]

Is there any way to "push" the column to the top when a smaller screen resolution is detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Just rearrange them and use push and pull

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-centered col-md-push-3">
    @include('schedulizer.schedule-panel')
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
    @include('schedulizer.classes-panel')
    @include('schedulizer.time-span-options-panel')
    @include('schedulizer.other-options-panel')
</div>
```

demo: http://www.bootply.com/GdWNOo6stu